# Flex 3 datagrid cell color

Tags: apache-flex, flex3

in flex 3 using itemrenderers how to change the background color for particular cell in datagrid.i am passing value from external xml filses.any one having idea?

Thanks,
aravindakumarThangaraju.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://butterfliesandbugs.wordpress.com/2007/07/11/using-an-itemrenderer-to-change-the-background-of-a-datagrid-cell/